# Use redis as a container in Azure Web App Service

Tags: azure, redis, azure-web-app-service

I've been trying for a week now to deploy a Redis Container as a Azure Web App Service, but I can't manage to connect to it, after a few tries some of the logs I got are listed bellow:

- The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format redis
- Protocol error, got "H" as reply type byte. Please report this.
- Redis error Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://*************.azurewebsites.net

Some of the things I tried:

- Different doors (80, 6379, random ones I saw in logs)
- Different TLS versions
- Force https connection

Does anyone of you know if it's possible to do it? I know there's Azure Redis but it's too pricey for a test.

Thanks alot

Comment: Can you share more details on how you are trying to deploy Redis container inside App Service. Some code samples or steps would be of great use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just figured out.

You actually have to deploy your container image using container instances, pointing the port 6379/TCP.

I did it and it worked fine.

Comment: Does the initial health check goes through? Cuz I have situation and the app service initial dummy request fails.

Comment: Isnt this solution at the end more expensive than just using Azure Redis Cache?

Comment: The draw back with Azure cache for Redis is that if you want to use the JSON module you need the premium tier, which is v. expensive.